# Laravel dynamic Subdomain with Path Routing

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, routes

Im a little bit confused about dynamic routing with laravel. in the documentation this point isnt documentated.

i would like to get a route for:

(user-slug).domain.com/(path-slug)

both details are written in my mysql database.

so what would be the best and securest solution.

thanks advance for all advices

Comment: Need more information. What is `user-slug` bound to? is it bound to the `user` model? what is `path-slug`? is this a page that the user has added? Is it a dynamic variable you which to have access to inside of a controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could do is create a route group like this:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{user}.domain.com'), function() {
    // Place your routes in here, like for example
    Route::get('/profile', 'Users\ProfileController@show'); 
});
```

The `user` parameter of the subdomain will then be able to be used as the first parameter of the method signature of **every** route that falls under this group. For methods without a `request`, it'll be the first parameter. For methods with a `request`, it'll be the second parameter, after the request.

The dependency injection works the same as with all other route params.

Hope this was the answer you were looking for.

Cheers!